# C++ Google Calendar API

Tags: c++, google-api

Hi All: I am supposed to provide Google calendar support on my C++ application running on Linux machine.
I came to know Google APIs Client Library for C++ is deprecated.So, I would like to know as to how I can provide calendar support in my Cpp application.

What steps should I follow and better if you redirect me to some URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use google calendar api using REST API.

[C++ Google Calendar REST API Examples](http://rest-examples.chilkat.io/google_calendar/cpp/default.cshtml)